# Como configurar el storage en un hosting laravel 9

Tags: laravel, hosting, storage

estoy comenzando con la subida del proyecto a un servidor compartido, todo iba bien hasta que probando los módulos, me di cuenta que en un formulario donde guardo unas imágenes y al querer editar los datos del formulario la imagen que subí no aparece. En la base de datos se almacena bien la ruta, pero en el servidor se guarda en otra carpeta, localmente si se guardan en el storage. Intente crear el enlace simbólico y me dice que ya existe
**Código para subir la imagen**

```
if($request->imagen)
{
    for( $i=0;$i<count($request->imagen);$i++ )
       {
           $ordenServicioImagenes=new OrdenServicioImagenes;
           if($request->imagen[$i]){               
               Storage::delete('public/'.$request->imagen[$i]);
               $name=$request->imagen[$i]->getClientOriginalName();
               $rutaImg=$request->imagen[$i]->store('fotosServicios','public'); 
                 
               $ordenServicioImagenes->foto=$rutaImg;     
               $ordenServicioImagenes->orden_servicio_id=$ordenServicio->id;
               $ordenServicioImagenes->descripcion=$request->descripcion[$i];
               $ordenServicioImagenes->save();
        }    
    }                
}
```

Comment: si es el mismo symlink de tu local en el server no te va a funcionar, borrarlo y volvelo a crear en el sistema del servidor

Comment: gracias por tu pronta respuesta, soy nuevo tanto en laravel como en trabajar con hosting, al decir borrarlo, lo borro como se borra una carpeta normal? y lo creo con el comando php artisan storage:link desde el terminal del hosting?

Comment: Listo, seguí tus indicaciones y ya se suben las imágenes y se pueden consultar, un millón de gracias - porloscerros

Comment: Genial que lo resolviste. Por favor agrega en una respuesta los pasos que hiciste, comandos que corriste, etc, así también le puede servir a otros

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver el problema que se me presento, realicé los siguiente

1. Desde CPanel, entre al administrador de archivos, me ubique en la carpeta que contiene mi proyecto (en mi caso lo tengo en un subdominio: services.midominio.cl), dentro de esta carpeta ubico la subcarpeta public y dentro de esta esta .storage, la selecciono y la elimino.
2. Una vez eliminada, desde ssh o la terminal del servidor (en algunos hosting no esta activada esta opción, se debe instalarl o pedirle al soporte del hosting que  la habiliten). Luego de tener habilitada la opción solo se debe ejecutar el siguiente comando `php artisan storage:link` (para crear el enlace simbólico) y ya se tendrá acceso a la carpeta para almacenar, las imágenes o documentos.

Espero poder aportar un poco en este fabuloso mundo de Laravel.